# reloadding .zshrc generate error with libiconv

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I get this error message when i reload my .zshrc

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/zsh
  Reason: Incompatible library version: zsh requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0
```

I looked around a  bit but i don't understand what I can do to fix it.

any idea?

Comment: I just removed and reinstalled zsh with brew. error message gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew uninstall zsh
```

then

```
brew install zsh
```

fixed it for me.